# Problem in route when not using the usb 4G dongle

Tags: pi-3b+, troubleshooting

I tried to plug in my E3372h Huawei modem, it was recognised automatically as an eth1, and the route -n showed 192.168.8.1 as default gateway, substituting the 0.0.0.0 default route accordingly (why?).
Once I removed it (restart etc etc), it never has the original default 0.0.0.0 anymore.

```
rpi@rpi:~ $ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.246.238.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wg0
```

What is happening?
Which tool is blocking rpi from setting up correctly the eth0?
I know it has to do with the usb dongle and the tool that is picking it up as an eth1 (which no longer exists if i remove it (shutdown , remove and then start rpi). Could it be the fault of usb-modeswitch (which I never touched btw)?

What can I do?

Edit: trying to fix it, I get....

```
pi@rpi:~ $ sudo route add -net 0.0.0.0 gw 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 
SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable
```

Edit #2:

This manual entry below makes it work. But how do I find the root cause and I make things automatic once again? I want to have a static IP as per the network manager options (which write to /etc/dchpcd.conf as far as I understand) and then reboot and have all the routes correct again.

```
i@rpi:~ $ sudo ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0
pi@rpi:~ $ sudo route add -net 0.0.0.0 gw 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
pi@rpi:~ $ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.246.238.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wg0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Edit #3:Version of pi is 3B+ with Buster as OS

```
i@rpi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
```

Edit #4:

```
pi@rpi:~ $ ip a && ip r
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:35:e9:89 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.39/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global deprecated noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a02:xxx:xx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 604799sec preferred_lft 604799sec
    inet6 fd00::39/128 scope global noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d0c9:104e:2eca:3e75/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:60:bc:dc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none 
    inet 10.246.238.1/24 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd11:5ee:bad:c0de::1/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10.246.238.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.246.238.1
```

Edit #5:

```
interface wlan0
inform 192.168.0.38
static routers=192.168.0.1

interface eth0
static routers=192.168.0.1
inform 192.168.0.39
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.39
static domain_search=192.168.0.39
static ip6_address=fd00::39

interface eth1
inform 192.168.8.100
static routers=192.168.8.1
metric 400
```

Adding ^the end of the /etc/dchpcd.conf

Comment: How in the world would we know anything about your Huawei modem? Please ask your question somewhere else.

Comment: @Milliways it is the Pi 3B
Linux rpi 5.10.103-v7+ #1529 SMP Tue Mar 8 12:21:37 GMT 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux                  
 
Seamus  it is the pi's behavior. I am asking how to find what blocks the pi from creating the default route from the beginning.

Comment: @Seamus it is the pi's behavior. I am asking how to find what blocks the pi from creating the default route from the beginning. Something happened withing Raspbian and a tool that pi is using to change the routes when I connected my usb dongle. It showed up as eth1 and it changed the default routes. Now that it is out of the picture, once I reboot, I no longer get the default routes. (I have also stopped wifi since a long time ago, but that is not the issue here).

Comment: Ok, sorry and edits done

Answer (score 0):

Now that we have established that you are running Buster (which uses `dhcpcd`) See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) which explains how to setup networking.

After you have setup post the output of `ip a && ip r`.

DO NOT attempt to fiddle with route - this is managed by `dhcpcd`.

Comment: Done and added the edn of /etc/dchpcd.conf (which I never changed). I know that something kicked in automatically when I put the dongle (eth1) and ever since it does not configure the routes.